# How to mass update a set of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to make a set of users inactive

```
params[:user_ids] = [1,5, 6, 9]
User.update_all({:status => 'Inactive'}, {:id => params[:user_ids]})
```

Will this set the status to inactive for the above 4 users or all users. I am not sure if I am using this correctly, my intention is to update status for the above 4 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.where(:id => params[:user_ids]).update_all(:status => 'Inactive') if params[:user_ids].present?
```

or

```
User.where('id IN (?)', params[:user_ids]).update_all(:status => 'Inactive') if params[:user_ids].present?
```

Comment: Will this be an issue if user_ids is empty? how should I prevent updates on such cases.

Comment: I think it should work without any issue if it an empty `array` and gives error if it is `nil`. You can try it on console. If it is giving error then use `if` : `User.where('id IN (?)', params[:user_ids]).update_all(:status => 'Inactive') if params[:user_ids].present?`